# Java League Table - Arrays based on user input

Tags: java, arrays

I need help with arrays. I need to print out a league table   based on user input. I know the names of the teams - held in an array. I need to ask the user for stats relating to each team in the array. How do I loop through each team in the array for this info such as "how many wins, draws, losses for?"  - would that pull the first team from the array?

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class RugbyProject {
final static int RESULT_POINTS_WIN = 2;
final static int RESULT_POINTS_DRAW = 1;
final static int RESULT_POINTS_LOSS = 0;
final static int GAME_POINTS_TRY = 5;
final static int GAME_POINTS_PENALTY = 3;
final static int GAME_POINTS_DROP_GOAL = 3;
final static int GAME_POINTS_CONVERISON = 2;


public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] teams = {"Ireland", "England", "France", "Wales", "Scotland",  "Italy"};

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome to The Six Nations Stats Centre. ");

for (int i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {

System.out.println("Please enter the number of wins for  " )[];}
int gamesWon = getIntFromUser("Enter whole number for wins please,   myScanner");
```

Comment: You access element at index `i` of an array `teams` using `teams[i]`, if that's your question. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: `getIntFromUser("Enter whole number for wins please,   myScanner");` ... you should recheck where the passed String should "end" ...

Comment: Okay so I did this and this prints out 6 separate questions for each team: Is it possible to ask one question at a time through a loop and then move onto the next question after user input?                                 for (String element : teams) {
         System.out.println("Please enter the number of wins, draws and losses for " + element);

Comment: Okay. This is what I have to date. Now how can I pull info from the scanner into separate arrays which are going to hold wins, draws, losses, etc.?